# angularjs set list of checkboxed checked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Well i've got 2 lists:

```
$scope.list = [{val: 1, name:'01'},{val: 2, name:'02'},{val: 3, name:'03'},{val: 4, name:'04'}]

$scope.selectedList = [{val: 2, name:'02'},{val: 4, name:'04'}]
```

and a list of comboboxes - generated by the list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list| filter: query">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-change="change(isDisabled,{{item.val}})" ng-model="isDisabled" /> {{item.name}}
 </div>
```

So how can I attach the selectedList to the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a ng-checked to the check box. Using a function as the expression, sending in the item that represents that check box.

```
ng-checked="isChecked(item)"
```

then the function just needs to return whether that item is in the selectedList

```
$scope.isChecked = function(item){

  return $scope.selectedList.indexOf(item) >-1;

};
```